# How to programmatically subscribe users to Firestore Topics?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

### Background

I want to have a notification that is sent to all users invoked by an HTTP request. Originally I was using batched writes. However, now our user base has outgrown the max batch size. I found that topics scale much larger

### Question

I have configured push notifications to be sent via FCM with topics. I have subscribed accounts to a "Global" topic upon account creation.
Now I need to programmatically add the rest of the user base to this topic. I cannot find any Firestore Documentation on how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using node:

```
    const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
    ...
    
    const messaging = firebaseAdmin.messaging();
    let FCMTokens = [] //registration tokens

    messaging.subscribeToTopic(FCMTokens, "TOPIC_NAME");
```

via http:

1- post to https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd

2- as headers send your Authorization (server key) and content-type as json

3- as body

```
{
    "to": "/topics/TOPIC_NAME",
    "registration_tokens": []
}
```